# Transparency with rgba does not work in Android Chrome

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

You may see the transparency in some divs which is achieved with rgba css property. However, Chrome in my tablet(ASUS) and my smartphone(Samsung S3 mini Galaxy) denies to follow these transparencies (Internet Explorer does follow!).
Why that? Is there any solution to this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate that problem, however the support of css3 colors is a recent addition in chrome for android

[somebody checked that for you](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors)

if you must support older browsers, I suggest reading this article on workarounds: [article on crossbrowser rgba colors](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/)